# How to calculate the database size from a full back up (.bak) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any standard calculation to convert `.bak` file size to actual database size?

My `.bak` is a full backup, not a compressed backup. It is 40 GB in file size from Azure SQL Server. It has production data.

Any help will be appreciated from database administrators.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Not by looking at the file size alone.

The reason is that a backup contains the used extents (one extent is eight 8KB pages). It doesn't contain un-used extent. However, the rastore command need a database where each database file has the same file at the database files had when you produced that backup. Thos file could have bunch of un-used extents, which aren't reflected in the file size.

For example, you could have a backup file of say 10MB, but the restore command need an mdf file with 100GB file size, since that was the file size when you took the backup. I.e., the database was close to empty.

The RESTORE FILELISTONLY command will tell you the file size for each database file that the RESTORE command need to create. This is what you are looking for. For instance:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'R:\mydb.bak'
WITH FILE = 1
```